# Java InetAddress.getHostName() taking a very long time to execute

Tags: java, inetaddress

I have the following little code snippet:

```
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        if(address.isReachable(TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS)) {
          System.out.println(host + " is reachable.");
          String hostName = address.getHostName();
          System.out.println(hostName);
        }
```

The getHostName() method is taking quite some time to execute if a machine has been found. Could someone please explain why?

Comment: How long is "quite some time" in your cases?

Answer (score 13):

From the [`InetAddress#getHostName()` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostName%28%29), that method will perform a [reverse hostname lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup).  So the performance of that method call depends on the performance of the network/technology stack between the JVM and the domain name server for the target host.

In brief, that method will make a system call to perform the reverse lookup (e.g. [`getaddrinfo(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo)) and that call will be implemented by the operating system to perform the network actions required to gather the host information via the [Name Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_server) configured for your machine.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the addresses need longer time to be resolved. InetAddress has a cache to store successful and unsuccessful resolutions. Also, make a threadpool. You can improve the performance

Answer (score 0):

`toString()` seems to be faster:

given an InetAddress ia or InterfaceAddress ia,

`System.out.println ( ia.toString() )` will show a string containing your ipAddress faster than `ia.getHostName()`

You can then use `ia.toString().substring` to extract it.

I don't know why.