# getCanonicalHostName is very slow

Tags: java, ip-address, hostname

```
InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress).getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName();
```

The above line takes around 10seconds to execute.

I added the IP and hostname in etc\hosts file and still there is no change.

How does getCanonicalHostName work? Can I get the implementation of that method?

How do I increase the efficiency of this line of code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289695/inetaddress-getlocalhost-slow-to-run-30-seconds and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420317/java-inetaddress-gethostname-taking-a-very-long-time-to-execute

Comment: Can u share the code for that function?

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was caused by the [Npcap](https://nmap.org/npcap/) driver, which I use for Wireshark. Disabling `Npcap Loopback Adapter` in Windows `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections` fixed the 9 seconds delay that I had.

The delay itself happens in the `Inet6AddressImpl.getHostByAddr(byte[] addr)` method (called by `InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName()`), which is native, so it's hard to say what's going on other than it's DNS related.

Answer (score 0):

When I Investigated the slow start of apache zookeeper on my windows, I had the same problem. zookeeper tries to get getCanonicalHostName which is very slow. So I tested the following code. The first log will output the ip which hostname will be obtained. I found that the ip(192.168.56.1) is not in my hosts file(C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts).

```
InetAddress localHost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
log.info(localHost);

String canonicalHostName = localHost.getCanonicalHostName();
log.info(canonicalHostName);
```

So I added the following line to hosts file, and the slow problem disappeared.

```
192.168.56.1        ip.of.vm
```